# Too many options with jEditable datatables plugin?

Tags: datatables, jeditable

This is driving me a bit insane, maybe someone has some insight to this. I have a jsp page with a editable datatable that I would like to have the following options

```
$("#masterTable").dataTable({
    "sDom" : '<"H"flp>t<"F"ip>r',
    "bJQueryUI" : true,
    "bStateSave" : true,
    "bProcessing" :true
}).makeEditable({
    "sAddURL" : "manager/add",
    "sDeleteURL" : "manager/delete",
    "sAddNewRowFormId" : "formAddNewRowId",
    "sAddNewRowButtonId" : "btnAddNewRowId",
    "sAddNewRowOkButtonId" : "btnAddNewRowOkId",
    "sAddNewRowCancelButtonId" : "btnAddNewRowCancelId",
    "sDeleteRowButtonId" : "btnDeleteRowId",
    "fnOnAdded" : function(){
        window.location.replace("/view/master.jsp");
    },
    "fnShowError" : function(message, action){
      switch(action){
          case "add":
              window.alert("Add Failed. Please check the error log for the exact problem");
              break;
          case "update":
              window.alert("Update Failed. Please check the error log for the exact problem");
              break;
          case "delete":
              window.alert("Delete Failed. Please check the error log for the exact problem");
              break;
      } 
    },
    "fnOnDeleted" : function(){
       window.location.replace("/view/report.jsp");
    },
    "aoColumns" : [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
});
```

But, when I try to load it, I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Error: Attempt to clear a buffer that's already been flushed
```

The insane part is, if I remove any two options, the page loads fine. It doesn't matter which two, or how many lines they are on(1 or separate), or if they are part of .dataTable or the .makeEditable but if I leave all the options, error. Is there some strange upper limit to the number of options that can be used on a table?